# addEventListener not firing paues and resume - Resume HTML5 audio after receiving a Phone Call or Notification on Android

Tags: android, html, audio, cordova, resume

I am developing a PhoneGap / JQMobile app that plays Audios on Android Phone from an Internet source. For this I am using HTML5 .

When a phone call comes in or a notification beeps for SMS etc., the Audio stops playing and doesn't resume afterwards. My understanding is that I should use addEventListner for "pause" and "resume" (and please correct me if I am wrong) to implement auto-restart functionality. However the respective callback functions for these events are not fired when a notification/call arrives or finishes.

Here is the eventlistner code and callback functions:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', deviceReady(), false);

function deviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("pause", AppPaused, false);
    document.addEventListener("resume", AppResumed, false);
}


function AppPaused()
{
    $(".message").text("Application Pause");
    alert("app paused");
    return;
}

function AppResumed()
{
    $(".message").text("Application Resumed");
    alert("app resumed");
    return;
}
```

Can someone please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks & Regards

AR

Comment: is this displaying any alert for alert("app resumed"); when you end the call

Comment: In fact, if I manually switch to another application it still doesn't show any message on leaving or coming back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   document.addEventListener("resume", AppResumed, false);
        function AppResumed() {
                   // Handle the resume event
                                   $(".message").text("Application Resumed");
                                   alert("app resumed");
                  }
});
```

**Edited:**

phonegap.js must be added and cordova js removed in order for this to work!

Comment: No it didn't work. Neither the message gets updated nor alert comes up.

Comment: have you add phonegap.js file in your html file

Comment: No, I didn't. Do I need to?

Comment: Now added phonegap.js which didn't work. I have added that before cordova.js and cordova-2.6.0.js because adding that after cordova disables other EvenListener events like menubutton and backbutton.

Comment: Just removed cordova's js files and it has started working? Do they conflict with each other? Thanks for the phonegap.js tip :-) Really appreciated.

I will now see if I am able to resume Audio!

Comment: Happy to know that It helped you. Enjoy coding.

Comment: Yes I am able to achieve my object. Thanks once again Andru :-)